Problemas con corchetes en jupyter notebook
tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy utilizando jupyter notebook pero tengo problemas con los corchetes, como muestra la imagen solo me deja hacerlo al principo y no deja cerrarlo:

y por ejemplo al definir una variable "a" y pasarle una lista no me deja abrir ni cerrar corchete como muestra la imagen:

que podra ser, ya que estos corchetes los puedo realizar perfectamente en una hoja excel con las teclas Alt +
sera configuracion del teclado? del propio jupyter notebook?
se agradece su ayuda, muchas gracias

Hola Roberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Seguramente se debe a esta issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15744. Parece que es un conflicto entre algunas distribuciones de teclado y los atajos de teclado.

El sistema operativo, la distribución de teclado y la versión de Jupyter Notebook/JupyterLabs que usas es información relevante,

Hola! gracias por la bienvenida
Esto es lo que tengo actualmente
Jupyter notebook 7.1.2
MacOs monterrey 12.7.4

Al parecer han tenido la brillante idea de poner como predeterminados los shortcuts "Alt + [" y "Alt + ]" que interfieren con el teclado en español, porque tienes que pulsar alt para acceder al corchete. Tendrás que entrar al menú settings -> settings editor -> keyboard shortcuts y pulsar en JSON Settings Editor. Ya verás en los comentarios del JSON System Defaults que hay que copiarlos en los settings del user y poner "disabled": true.
